# WPF implicit DataTemplate declared in App.xaml won't take effect

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, app.xaml

In the `MainWindow.xaml`, I set:

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

In the `App.xaml` file, I added the following:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="vm:MainViewModel">
    <v:MainView/>
  </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

I was hoping the `MainWindow` will automatically load and show the `MainView` with its `DataContext` property set to the windows's one (which was set to `MainViewModel` at design-time as above), but it won't work - the `MainWindow` doesn't use the `DataTemplate` set in `App.xaml`.

Any better ideas for this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a minor changes -

First, in your window.  Try this:

```
<Window>
  <!-- setup window... -->

  <ContentPresenter>
      <ContentPresenter.Content>
          <vm:MainViewModel/>
      </ContentPresenter.Content>
  </ContentPresenter>      
</Window>
```

This creates a single content item within your Window.  DataTemplates work by mapping *content* to a new View - in this case, since the Content here is the `MainViewModel`, it will automatically create and instantiate a new `MainView` for you.  Setting the `DataContext` will not trigger `DataTemplates`, since you're never making the ViewModel "content" of an object.

You can shorten this by just setting the Window's Content directly, if you prefer:

```
<Window>
  <Window.Content>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
  </Window.Content>
</Window>
```

Or, even, binding the Content to the `DataContext` (though this only makes sense if you need the `DataContext` set for some other purpose):

```
<Window Content="{Binding}">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

Comment: Is there a more generic way to make it rely on the App.xaml settings?

Comment: @Shimmy: What are you trying to do?  What you had put in place is effectively trying to "turn the Window into a MainView", which will not work.  You need to set the content of the Window, at some point, to your ViewModel, and it works.  You can actually just use `<Window.Content><vm:MainViewModel /></Window.Content>` instead of putting in a `ContentPresenter`, if you'd like (I just feel the other is a bit more clear...)

Comment: I've updated your answer for clarity and brevity. That answered my question.

Comment: @Shimmy: Personally, I would just set the Content, and leave the DataContext alone... but you can do it this way, too, if you prefer ;)

Comment: Once you've set the Content, there's really no reason at all to set DataContext like this....

Comment: The reason I do it this way, is because really the container itself (in this case the Window) needs access to the ViewModel. Think of an example `<Window Title="{Binding CurrentFile}"/>` or something similar. Anyway thanks for helping me finding a solution.

Comment: @Shimmy: Yes, if you need that, then it's useful ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think you need

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainViewModel}">
```

**EDIT:**

I really don't think I'm wrong, the code

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <WpfApplication1:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication1:ViewModel}">
        <TextBlock>Custom template</TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
```

shows “Custom template”. If I remove the `x:Type`, what's shown instead is “WpfApplication1.ViewModel”, which is the result of calling `ToString()` on the view model object. This is used in the absence of a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: `"{x:Type vm:MainViewModel}"` is essentially just the same as `"vm:MainViewModel"`. WPF has a type convertor that interprets the string as it would have been a type, so unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: @Shimmy, yeah but that type converter isn't applied for `DataType`, because its type is `object`. So you need to use `x:Type`, [the documentaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) even mentions it.

Comment: you're wrong. The documentation metioned that you should use `typename` which can be interpreted from a string.

Comment: This can be required at times - From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx - "In specific framework implementations, some properties that take Type as a value can accept the name of the type directly"  This will typically work (without the markup extension), however, there are scenarios where it fails.  In general, I prefer using the `{x:Type` extension for clarity, but it is not always required.

Comment: @Shimmy, I think the documentation is wrong at least at one count: `x:Type` is not used to refer to a type *name*, it's used to refer to the `Type` object.

Comment: Coming from Silverlight, the {x:Type datatype} was the difference to make it work in WPF. In Silverlight it was just "datatype"